# Permission denied (publickey) with bitami AMI & EC2

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I created an EC2 instance using a bitami AMI.  I created a ec2 key pair using ec2-add-keypair utility

when I tried `ssh -i id_rsa-my-keypair bitami@<myinstance> -v`

I got the following error

```
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: settwo_05012012.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: id_rsa-my-keypair
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

The interesting thing is that I tried create another instance using the same keypair with an ubuntu ami, I have no problem getting in.  I already rule out port 22 issue. I really want to use this bitami. Help would be much appreciated.

Here are few lines in the ssh config

```
cat ssh_config|grep -v "#"

Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: ssh -i id_rsa-my-keypair bitnami@myinstance -v

User should be **bitnami** not bitami.